# JSF <ui:include /> Recursion Causes java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, recursion, facelets

I have, what I would assume, is a pretty common use case.  We're rendering a simple "Comments" page using JSF on Wildfly 10.0.  Each comment may have a parent comment, and child comments underneath it.  Since there's no way to know ahead of time what the structure is, we'd like to create a JSF fragment and `<ui:include />` it recursively to render the contents.  It would look something like this...

Main page:

```
<ul class="comments>
  <ui:repeat value="#{myObj.comments}" var="comment">
    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/fragments/comment.xhtml">
      <ui:param name="comment" value="#{comment}" />
    </ui:include>
  </ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

Comment Fragment:

```
<li><h:outputText value="#{comment.text}">
  <ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty comment.childComments}">
    <ul class="comments">  
      <ui:repeat value="#{comment.childComments}" var="comment">
        <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/fragments/comment.xhtml">
          <ui:param name="comment" value="#{comment}" />
        </ui:include>
      </ui:repeat>
    </ul>
  </ui:fragment>
</li>
```

However, when I run this code, the recursion seems to cause  `java.lang.StackOverflowError`, regardless of how many items there are.  Additionally, we see a `javax.servlet.ServletException` saying, `"Could not Resolve Variable [Overflow]"`

Is there a reason why this recursive call results in this Exception?  Is there a better way to accomplish this?  I've tried using `<c:forEach />` to iterate over the comments, however when I do this it does not appear to work in JSF.  I've tried both the `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core` and `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core` namespaces for the taglib, but the `<c:forEach />` tag doesn't seem to iterate over my objects.  (That is, nothing is being rendered to the page)

Any help you can give would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: It appears from what you've posted that `/WEB-INF/fragments/comment.xhtml` contains a `ui:include` that includes _itself_.  This would cause infinite recursion and eventually consume all of memory.

Comment: No, you'll notice that the comment fragment has a <ui:fragment /> call in it that only recursively adds itself if the comment has child comments.  I'm assuming that as long as it doesn't infinitely include itself that this should be fine.

Comment: I blogged about a similar construct with composites few days ago: http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2016/02/recursive-tree-of-composite-components.html It should provide insight.

Comment: Use a different name for the inner `var` item.

Comment: @EJP: No, that won't work as problem already occurs during view build time. Basically, an infinite component tree is being built as the `<ui:repeat>` only considers its condition during view render time. Shadowman, JSTL is part of the solution. How exactly does it fail for you? Where does `#{myObj}` come from? It would fail if it in turn also comes from  `var` of `<ui:repeat>` or `<h;dataTable>`.

Comment: This duplicates your functional requirement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918137/component-to-iterate-and-render-a-nested-tree-like-object-structure-in-jsf This answers your technical problem with current attempt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense